# How to migrate the second db in django

Tags: django, database

I have two databases, one is default and the other one as first what I want is made some changes in  first_db and now I want to migrate.

In my settings.py:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ('app.router.DatabaseRouter',)

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'primary_name',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
       
    },
    'first': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'secondary_name',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        
    }
}
```

I tried the command python manage.py migrate --database=first it showed it got migrated then when i tried to do python manage.py makemigrations it said all migrations are done and when i tried to run server and trying to insert some value in some table of first it started giving me error like the column I added is not there can anyone help me.

I think the migration didn't happen actually so anyone can show me how correctly migrate when having multiple database.

Comment: python manage.py migrate --database=first

Comment: i already did that i already mentioned that in my problem that problem i am having is not able to migrate

Comment: Show us your view logic please.

Comment: which logic everything i gave  possibly all that i can give

Comment: Show your code for `app.router.DatabaseRouter`...

Comment: there is noting to show for app.router.databaseRouter

Answer (score 0):

Migrations are done in database named 'first'.

***if you want to migrate them to default database too just in case, then run:***

```
python3 manage.py migrate
```

***otherwise run:***
python3 manage.py migrate --fake     #To fake migration in default db for resolving runtime error

***And to insert some value into table:***

ModelName.objects.using('first').create(id=1  .......(other_datas)

[Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/)

Comment: i was able to sucessfully migrate but couldn't do makemigrations for first

Comment: You don't need to, it's done when you did makemigrations for first database untill you migrate it to default database.